# Error installing node-sass using local binary

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, jenkins, node-sass

I'm using node 14 and Jenkins behind a corporate proxy I can't get node-sass to install properly.

So I've installed it locally in two places

- For SASS_BINARY_PATH: `/var/jenkins_home/linux-x64-83_binding.node`
- For SASS_BINARY_DIR: `/var/jenkins_home/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node`

I tried `SASS_BINARY_PATH`:

```
SASS_BINARY_PATH=/var/jenkins_home/linux-x64-83_binding.node npm install node-sass
npm install --no-lockfile
npm run build
```

But I get this error when building:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/root_project_dir/project/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'

And I tried `SASS_BINARY_DIR`:

```
SASS_BINARY_DIR=/var/jenkins_home/vendor npm install node-sass
npm install --no-lockfile
npm run build
```

But this ends up trying to download the binary which is the problem I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my package.json if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.115",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.48",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "0.7.0",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "typescript": "^3.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-async-computed": "^3.3.1",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by manually creating the `node_modules/node-sass/vendor` directory after `npm install` and copying the `binding.node` into the `linux-x64-83` directory:

```
npm install node-sass --sass-binary-path="/var/jenkins_home/linux-x64-83_binding.node"
npm install --no-lockfile
mkdir -p node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83
cp /var/jenkins_home/linux-x64-83_binding.node node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
npm run build
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. :hat-tip:

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an empty directory `C:\res\node-sass`, which will be used as `SASS_BINARY_DIR`. The following steps show how I specify `SASS_BINARY_DIR` correctly:

- install your package with `npm install` under your project root
  In the content printed in the console, find a link similar to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-83_binding.node
- manually download the https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-83_binding.node, and save it as `win32-x64-83_binding.node`
- create a subdirectory called `win32-x64-83` under C:\res\node-sass, notice that  `win32-x64-83` comes from part of the filename `win32-x64-83_binding.node`
- copy the downloaded win32-x64-83_binding.node into the folder C:\res\node-sass\win32-x64-83, and rename the file to `binding.node`
- add `SASS_BINARY_DIR=C:\res\node-sass` to .npmrc under the application root
- keep downloading with `npm i`
  This time, npm will go to SASS_BINARY_DIR find the binary source instead of downloading it from github.

So the downloaded `win32-x64-83_binding.node` actually becomes `%SASS_BINARY_DIR%\win32-x64-83\binding.node`

In addition to specifying SASS_BINARY_DIR in file `.npmrc`, you can also export it as environment variable with `set SASS_BINARY_DIR=C:\res\node-sass` on windows.